# Using conditional definitions with variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, enable-if

If I have a template function which takes a known number of template arguments, I can use the `enable_if` statement along with things like `is_base_of` to limit the legal types. For example:

```
template <typename T>
typename enable_if<is_base_of<BaseClass, T>::value, void>::type
function() {
    // do stuff with T, which is ensured to be a child class of BaseClass
}
```

Now suppose we want to do the same thing for a variadic template - check to make sure all types are children of a specific base class.

```
template <typename... T>
/* What goes here? */
function() {
    // do stuff with the T types, which are ensured to be child classes of BaseClass
}
```

How would you go about writing this conditional definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the following type_traits:

```
template <typename Base, typename T, typename... Ts>
struct are_base_of :
    std::conditional<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, are_base_of<Base, Ts...>,
                     std::false_type>::type
{};

template <typename Base, typename T>
struct are_base_of<Base, T> : std::is_base_of<Base, T> {};
```

And then use

```
template <typename... Ts>
typename std::enable_if<are_base_of<BaseClass, Ts...>::value, void>::type
function() {
    // do stuff with Ts, which is ensured to be a child class of BaseClass
}
```

Comment: +1 for a moment I didn't see the base-expansion (don't ask; its late here). Nicely crafted.

Comment: Cool - so the `are_base_of` struct recursively inherits from `is_base_of` for every type in `Ts`. Thanks Jarod!